# Prove that $n$ lines form $[n(n+1)/2]+1$

Tags: induction, plane-geometry

I saw the same formula on the web as $(n^2+n+2)/2$. I saw the same problem [here](https://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437160/induction-proof-n-lines-in-a-plane&ved=2ahUKEwiywpya2fHdAhVmpIsKHTeXCosQjjgwAHoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3ypogQnsqavMEFVEnrjDGA).
However, I didn't understand very well. I have to prove it and it seems I should use induction. 
So I decided to do it "my way, which I can understand for myself": ( :-) )

1. I proved that with $n=1$, the formula works
2. I assume it works with $n=k => [k(k+1)/2] $should be equal to the number of planes, made by k lines.
3. But then I cannot reach the same formula for $k+1$

I have noticed however the following (let's say I add the$ (k+1)$th line):
This line can be split by theother lines into $k+1$ parts and can therefore add $k+1$ more planes. 
Then the number of planes should be:
$1+2+3+4+...+k+k+1$ but that equals $[(k+1)(k+2)/2].$ The $ +1$ is missing. What's wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "n lines form (some expression)". Your question is not clear. Do you mean partitions of the plane?

Comment: The $k+1$st line intersects all previous $k$ lines, hence passes through $k+1$ regions and increases the region count by $k+1$. If we had $\frac{k^2+k+2}2$ regions before, we now have $\frac{k^2+k+2}2+k+1=\frac{k^2+3k+4}2=\frac{(k+1)^2+(k+1)+2}2$

Comment: @DavidPeterson I don't know tge terminology in English but I think it's regions.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen By using your equation, I proved the 3rd point and the problem! Thank you! You should have written it as an answer,so I could accept it!